# Under what circumstances are Russian words spelled phonetically in Ukrainian Cyrillic?

Tags: transliteration

I was looking at a primarily Ukrainian language meme account and in one screenshot I saw the word "Прівєт". Is this kind of phonetic transcription common? When is it used?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, there are many "legitimate" uses for loanwords, especially the proper names like family names, toponyms, etc. For example, the Russian <s>Prime Minister</s> <s>President</s> Prime Minister's family name <sub>Rus.</sub>*Медведев* is written [*Медвед**є**в*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%94%D0%B2_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) in Ukrainian, and there are plenty of uses like *М**є**дв**є**д**є**в*, which is arguably a better match with the original phonology:

> *Прем'єр РФ **Мєдвєдєв** пропонує перейменувати «американо» на «русіано»* — [Hromadske TV](http://hromadske.ua/posts/premier-rf-miedviediev-proponuie-pereimenuvaty-amerykano-na-rusiano)

---

#### But yes, you've noticed a rather popular phenomenon.

[Cacography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacography) is deliberate misspelling intended to convey humorous sense or just exaggerating someone's style or illiteracy.

See also [Sensational spelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensational_spelling). It has similar effect, but using literate, but rare or dialectal spelling of a word or phrase.

In this particular case, some Ukrainian speaker is ridiculing about someone who speaks Russian or a [Surzhyk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surzhyk).

This phenomenon has risen a lot since the times of Russian armed invasion to Ukraine, where one of the Russian self-excuses was **"Defending the Russian-speakers"** (of Ukraine). In reality, the first thing the occupants have done is they began a **forced russification** on the occupied territories.

The following photo shows a road sign at the entry to Donets'k city after the forced russification by the occupants; they have removed the "soft sign", and «ДОНЕЦ**Ь**К» became «ДОНЕЦК».

[image: Donets'k after forced russification]

And, most obviously, this forced russification has naturally caused resistance among the Ukrainians, even the Russian-speaking ones. They started *mocking the Russian language* as in your example.

---

#### Usage guides

So, since the phenomenon is not linguistic, but rather political and social, I would not recommend a language learner to use it, unless you know what you are doing.

From the linguistic point, *Cacography* is a power tool, but also it's like a "thin ice"; it is easy to "slip off" the right track:

- do it less than needed, and you look like an illiterate person;
- do it more than needed, and you end up writing something incomprehensible.