# What kind of grammatical errors would I use to make a joke about how I can't speak Ukrainian?

Tags: граматика, non-native-speaker

[Bytebuster's answer](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/888/259) to my last question alerted me to the name of the phenomenon of [Cacography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacography). (Yes, I understand that cacography relates to spelling and my question relates to grammar).

Since I don't expect to be fluent for some time, I figure that I might as well have fun with my ineptitude.

An English equivalent would be something along the lines of:

> I no speak the English very good.

Comment: Can you please re-phrase the Q so that it didn't ask for an open-ended list? This is considered opinion-based at StackExchange.

Comment: I bet, any ad-hoc joke of given kind may be easily reduced to suržek, and suržek is hell serious. You may try to apply English grammar to Ukrainian - it wouldn't look like real joke and you'll sound silly, but at least you'd try

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An equivalent for

> I no speak the English very good.

could be

> Моя не говорити український дуже добре.

Compare it with a correct version:

> Я не дуже добре говорю українською [по-українськи].

The errors:

1) usage of *моя* (*mine*) instead of *я* (*I*).

2) usage of infinitive form of *говорити* (*to speak*) instead of Present tense form *говорю* (*speak*).

3) usage of *український [мова]* (*Ukrainian [language]*) in masculine gender instead of feminine gender – *українська*

4) missing Instrumental case for *українська*. Should be *українською*.

5) negation is applied to the verb instead of adverbial. Notice, that both "Я *не дуже добре* говорю" and "Я говорю *не дуже добре*" variants are OK.

Comment: You may want to include into your answer the phrase *«моя твоя не розумій»*, too. [A simple googling](https://www.google.com/search?q="моя+твоя+не+розумій") yields 146 results.